# Align full width image with SVG mask on the right, outside container with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align an image with a SVG mask to the right, outside of a container but it causes overflow. When I reverse it and align the image on the left it does not cause an overflow.

Currently I am using the following code to align the image to the right:

```
.alignfull {
margin-right: calc(100% - 50vw);
}
```

If there's a better way of doing it, any tips are welcome. I am trying it this way to keep the content vertical center aligned with the content in the container. `position: absolute;` is therefore not really a solution as far as I know.

Here's a codepen to demonstrate of what I am having now: https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/pobzaVB

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you set a `container` class that dont take the whole width. If you want that it take the whole width, you need to it with `container-fluid` and add `pd-md-0` to remove the padding-right from it.

Then I add an `offset-sm-2` that is adding 2 empty column on the left to keep space between the left and the text:

```
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
```

And I removed your margin and your `col-lg-6` that are useless when you apply `col-md-6`

### DEMO

```css
.img-shape {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 1048 909" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M695.513 113.586C697.313 112.186 698.813 110.286 700.613 108.786C719.513 92.586 736.913 74.886 753.913 56.886C770.413 39.286 790.113 26.286 812.413 17.686C862.013 -1.51404 913.113 -4.81404 965.113 6.48596C994.813 12.886 1022.41 24.086 1047.21 41.786C1047.21 319.486 1047.21 597.086 1047.21 874.786C1039.31 879.986 1031.71 885.786 1023.21 890.086L1008.61 896.686C991.313 904.186 973.013 908.086 954.213 908.686C922.213 909.686 890.313 907.386 859.113 899.686C836.913 894.186 815.113 887.886 793.613 879.986C770.013 871.286 746.913 861.186 723.913 851.086C680.113 831.986 636.613 811.986 591.713 795.586C562.613 784.986 533.413 774.686 503.213 767.486C499.613 766.586 496.013 765.786 492.413 764.886L436.213 753.686C436.213 753.686 400.513 749.286 382.613 747.286C341.013 742.686 299.313 741.586 257.513 740.986C223.813 740.486 190.113 742.286 156.513 739.586C117.213 736.486 82.2127 722.086 53.7127 694.586C18.2127 660.386 2.7127 617.086 0.212701 568.886C-1.2873 539.986 5.2127 512.186 17.6127 485.986C29.7127 460.586 47.1127 439.786 71.4127 424.986C86.9127 415.586 103.213 407.486 118.313 397.286C135.013 385.986 150.513 373.386 163.813 358.486C177.913 342.686 188.113 323.986 197.813 305.086C207.013 286.986 214.513 267.986 223.513 249.786C238.313 219.686 258.713 194.386 288.613 177.986C315.413 163.286 344.613 158.086 374.713 156.686C406.213 155.186 437.713 157.386 469.013 161.086C486.413 163.186 503.813 164.386 521.113 167.486C534.213 169.886 547.513 171.986 560.713 172.386C590.013 173.286 617.313 164.886 642.813 150.786C653.913 144.686 664.613 137.986 674.813 130.386L695.513 113.586Z"/></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.alignfull {
    /*margin-right: calc(100% - 50vw);*/
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .img-shape {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-mask: none;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    .alignfull {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section class="">
    <div class="container-fluid pr-md-0 vh-100 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="row mx-0 align-items-center flex-row-reverse h-100">
            
            <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-0 h-100">
                <div class="alignfull d-flex h-100">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/800" class="img-shape ml-md-auto my-auto">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2 h-100 d-flex">
                <div class="title-heading my-auto">
                    <h1 class="heading mb-3">Work Smart. <br> Not Hard.</h1>
                    <p class="para-desc text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co&nsectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris faucibus aliquet ipsum, quis ornare orci euismod ut. Curabitur vel orci eu libero fermentum efficitur. Morbi fermentum a nisi sit amet ultrices.</p>
                    <div class="mt-4 pt-2">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I like your approach. And you're right, some classes are redundant but it is merely an example of what I am actually working on. However in your example it still has an overflow

Comment: @Mark I edited. You need to add h-100 on container until the image on which you apply `max-width: 100%;` and `max-height: 100%;` Please let me know if it is okay by you

Comment: I also saw that you added a margin on img on small width screen, I advice you to set that on container where you have cold-md-6, other with it wont fit as in the example.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is still a overflow visible in Chrome as well as FF.

Comment: There is an overflow on the x axis. It creates a scrollbar on the bottom.

Comment: @Mark That is fixed, it was the margin on the `row` class that added automaticly margin. Here you go